# optiPNG bat file for subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I've been using optiPNG for some time now.
I'm using this simple .bat file:

```
C:\optipng\optipng.exe -log C:\optipng.log -force -v -o2 "%cd%\*.png"
```

It optimizes every PNG file where the .bat file is located. But I want it to cover the entire folder where the file is located including every .png file in the subfolders.
Something like "%cd%\EVERY_SUBFOLDER*.png" but I'm not really a professional when it comes to using CMD. My Windows is Win7 Home Basic.

Would be nice if there was a function to also add so that the window doesn't close after executing the file.

Answer (score 5):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (*.png) DO (
 ECHO(C:\optipng\optipng.exe -log C:\optipng.log -force -v -o2 "%%a"
)
pause
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, delete the string `ECHO(` which appears before your command to actually execute the commands.